# Do I need to have images in DOM to merge them using canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I would like to merge two images using canvas. But do I need to have them in DOM? what if I have many images, have url, but I don't want to preload them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to have them in DOM. Simple `new Image( 'path/to/image.jpg' )` will work for you.

But don't forget to merge them only after `onload` event as without it your merge functionality can work unexpectable.

Comment: Can you give me simplest example of png merge? both transparent sources?

Comment: It's simple `ctx.drawImage( img, x, y )` method.

Comment: what about canvas element do I have to have it in dom?

Comment: nope, this is not necessary. You can just make `document.createElement( 'canvas' )` but without inserting it to DOM